# I am not able to use texture paint (2.8)

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-painting

Every time I try to use the texture paint, I am met with an error card saying "Missing UVs, Textures, detected!". Any help please?

Comment: You need to add a UV texture. You can do this by selecting the "new texture" button in the settings.

Comment: Where are the settings? Sorry, I'm brand new and the UI is a little confusing to me

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an image open in the *Image Editor*.

Pressing the small picture icon will allow you to select existing images in your project. *New* will create a new blank image, and *Open* will allow you to append an image from your computer into the Blend project.

[image]

If there are missing textures from your project (those show up as pink), you can tell Blender which folders to look for those textures in by going to *File* > *External Data* > *Find Missing Files*

[image]